# Is there a method to get the fist letter of each string capitalized and return an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings and have to map through them and get an array with the first letter capitalized

I've tried both the splice and slice method for this, but didn't succesed. I then looked at charAt() but only got the first letter capitalized without the rest of the string.I am new to JavaScript

Comment: Welcome (back) to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+capitalize+each+string+in+array) before posting (more about searching [here](/help/searching)), and in particular before posting a self-answer. Self-answered questions are encouraged, but only when they add useful information to the site that isn't already here.

Answer (score -1):

const capitalized = names.map( (string) => string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.substr(1))
console.log(capitalized)